# How to exclude searching specified fields using Zend Search (Lucene)

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, full-text-search, lucene

I've built a search index using the PHP Zend Framework Search (based on Lucene).  The search is for a buy/sell website.

My search index includes the following fields:

item-id (UnIndexed)
item-title (Text)
item-description (UnStored)
item-tags (Text) 
item-price (keyword)
seller-id (UnIndexed)
seller-name (Text)

I want the user to search the index, filtering their search by either only searching for items or searching for sellers by name.

If I do a search using Lucene's default search settings I will be searching all 5 item fields and the seller-name field.  This is not what I want to happen.  What I would like is when the user makes the search I want them to be required to select from a drop-down menu if they are searching for an item, or for a seller-name.

How can I tell the search query when searching for items to ignore the seller-name field?  And when searching for seller-name's how can i tell the search query to not search across any of the item fields?  Or is it better to create a separate index for the seller names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's currently no way to explicitly *not* search a field in Lucene's query language, or the `Zend_Search_Lucene` query constructing API.

However, you can explicitly list which fields you *do* want to search in a query. An example would be:

```
seller-name: Joe McBob
```

If using this approach, you will have to explicitly list which fields you want to query, and what to search in them. So if you also needed to search your `item-title` field with the same text, you would have to duplicate the above, but with the different field name. An example would be:

```
seller-name: Joe McBob OR item-title: JoeMcBob
```

You can, of course, do all this through the query building API that `Zend_Search_Lucene` provides, as well. The [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-api.html) has some good examples there.

One thing worth noting here is that, as you've discovered, `Zend_Search_Lucene` will search ALL fields by default. This is one of the ways in which it differs from Java Lucene.
You may, however, set a default field to query, using the `setDefaultSearchField` static method of the `Zend_Search_Lucene` class.

Comment: Thanks jason.  I figured that's what I may have to do. I wanted to double check the knowledge base here to see if there was a better solution and you have satisfied my question!